# Remove charcaters from fasta header

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fasta

I have a fasta file, has a  header like:

`>NC_000002.12 Homo sapiens chromosome 2, GRCh38.p14 Primary Assembly`

I want to remove everything after `NC_000002.12.`.
I am running the script on ubuntu. I have tried:

```
sed -E 's/^>?([^|]+).*/\1/' *.fasta
```

but it didn't work. Please help

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974459/remove-all-letters-after-space-in-a-line-that-start-with-specific-character

Comment: I also recommend that you check out seqkit (http://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#replace). This can easily be solved with `seqkit replace -p "\s.+" file.fasta`.